# Non-overlapping geometries from two different objects in R

Tags: r, overlapping-features, sf

I can select geometries that overlap from two objects (basic example):

```
library(sf)
# create a  simple square
sq <- rbind(c(3, 3), c(15, 3), c(15, 15), c(3, 15), c(3, 3)) %>% list %>% st_polygon %>% st_sfc

# then random points
pon <- runif(30, -1, 15) %>% cbind(runif(30, -1, 15)) %>% st_multipoint %>% st_sfc %>% st_cast("POINT")

plot(sq)
plot(pon, add=TRUE)

# indicate points that intersect the square
inter=st_intersection(pon, sq)

plot(sq)
plot(inter, add= TRUE)
```

But now I want to select those points not-overlapping the square. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider subsetting the `pon` object with negated vector of `st_intersects()` results = selecting those points, for which st_intersects is not valid. You will need to specify `sparse = FALSE` setting, so the output of intersection will be a logical vector (and not a sparse matrix).

```
library(sf)
# create a  simple square
sq <- rbind(c(3, 3), c(15, 3), c(15, 15), c(3, 15), c(3, 3)) %>% list %>% st_polygon %>% st_sfc

# then random points
pon <- runif(30, -1, 15) %>% 
  cbind(runif(30, -1, 15)) %>% 
  st_multipoint %>% 
  st_sfc %>% 
  st_cast("POINT")

plot(sq)
plot(pon, add=TRUE)

# subset points that do not intersect witht the square
# note the not st_intersects
diff <- pon[!st_intersects(pon, sq, sparse = F)]

plot(sq)
plot(diff, add= TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! That solves my question. Thanks, @Jindra.